# Using VLOOKUP with dynamic range array

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a sheet with a list of email addresses that is being auto-updated (more email addresses being added on a daily basis). I have a second  sheet with a list of email addresses that have been contacted (marked TRUE).

I would like to add a column to the first sheet indicating which addresses have been marked as contacted, using the email addresses from the second sheet.

I can accomplish this with VLOOKUP, but since I'll be adding addresses to the second sheet, the range is a growing list.

Is it possible to have a function that checks over the growing list of contacted emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula like this:

```
=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

copied down in your first sheet may serve.

Comment: This is right, you can fine tune with A1:A etc

Comment: I mean,  =vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A1:A,2,0)  is also possible

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. I didn't realize that you could set the range to span the entirety of both columns with `, Sheet2!A:B`. Thank you!